# How to use Flow with create-react-app for runtime type checks?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, flowtype, typechecking, react-proptypes

I am using `Flow` for static typing in my `create-react-app` project. I would like to also use it to check types at runtime.

There are babel plugins that auto-generate `proptypes` from `Flow types` such as [babel-plugin-flow-react-proptypes](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-flow-react-proptypes). But that requires `babelrc` modification.

There's also [flow-runtime](https://github.com/gajus/flow-runtime/tree/master/packages/flow-runtime), "*A runtime type system for JavaScript with full Flow compatibility.*", whatever that is.

Is it possible to get either running with `create-react-app`, or maybe another way of achieving a similar result?

Comment: Look at https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-flow

Comment: I already have Flow in my project, but it only does static typing, not runtime checks.

Comment: Look at https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/1152